# Prove $\mid f(x_{1})-f(x_{2})\mid<\varepsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

If $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$ then

$\forall \varepsilon>0$ $\exists \delta>0$ s.t. $ 0<\mid x_{1} -a\mid<\delta_{1}$, $0<\mid x_{2} -a\mid<\delta \implies \mid f(x_{1})-f(x_{2})\mid<\varepsilon$.

Wondering what my $\delta$ would be, would it be something with a minimum including $\delta_{1}$? We haven't done any proofs with multiple deltas very formally so I'm not sure how to write it.

Comment: HINT: You have to use the triangular inequality $$|f(x_1) - f(x_2)| \le |f(x_1)-L|+|f(x_2)-L|$$ If the two summands on the right are smaller than $\varepsilon/2$, then you are done.

Answer (score 2):

By definition of the mimit, there is $\delta $ s.t.  $|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon /2$.

Therefore, if $|x_1-a|,|x_2-a|<\delta $, then $$|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|\leq |f(x_1)-L|+|f(x_2)-L|<\varepsilon .$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $:$ Observe that $$|f(x_1) - f(x_2)| \leq |f(x_1) - L| + |f(x_2)-L|.$$